# Adicionar campos em um select

Tags: sql, postgresql, query

Como que coloca o idautor e o idobra nesse meu SELECT:

```
CREATE TABLE Obra_Assunto (
            idassunto INTEGER NOT NULL,
            idobra INTEGER NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (idassunto, idobra),
            FOREIGN KEY (idobra)REFERENCES Obra (idobra),
            FOREIGN KEY (idassunto)REFERENCES Assunto (idassunto)
            );

CREATE TABLE Obra_Autor (
            idobra INTEGER NOT NULL,
            idautor INTEGER NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (idobra, idautor),
            FOREIGN KEY (idobra)REFERENCES Obra (idobra),
            FOREIGN KEY (idautor)REFERENCES Autor (idautor)
            );

CREATE TABLE Assunto (
            idassunto INTEGER NOT NULL,
            descricaoAssunto VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (idassunto)
            );

CREATE TABLE Autor (
            idautor INTEGER NOT NULL,
            nomeAutor VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (idautor)
            );


CREATE TABLE Obra (
            idobra INTEGER NOT NULL,
            titulo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            ano_publicacao INTEGER NOT NULL,
            quantidade INTEGER NOT NULL,
            ideditora INTEGER NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (idobra),
            FOREIGN KEY (ideditora)REFERENCES Editora (ideditora)
            );

select nomeAutor,titulo,descricaoAssunto 
  from autor a , obra_autor oa , obra o , obra_assunto os, assunto ass
Where a.idautor= oa.idautor AND oa.idobra= o.idobra AND o.idobra= os.idassunto AND os.idassunto= ass.idassunto;
```

Comment: só colocar `select o.idobra, a.idautor` ... group by você só usa quando trabalhar com função de agregação

Comment: Bom dia, como assim função de agregação ?

Comment: funções de agregação: `max`, `sum`, `min`, `avg` entre outras....

Comment: Mas tipo assim , só vale para duas tabelas ?

Comment: oi ? leia / assista: https://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-funcoes-de-agregacao/38463

Comment: Mas em uma tabela só é simples, eu quero saber como que faz em várias tabelas ?

Comment: da mesma forma... 1 ou n tabelas, só muda os joins, o que você faz com as colunas, é o mesmo... a resposta do lacobus deu certo ?

Comment: deu sim , inclusive boa resposta.

Comment: então marque-a como resposta da questão, e se achar válido, avalie-a como +1

Comment: acesse o [Tour] por favor

Answer (score 2):

Já tentou algo como:

```
SELECT
    a.idautor,
    a.nomeAutor,
    o.idobra,
    o.titulo,
    ass.descricaoAssunto 
FROM
  autor AS a
JOIN
  obra_autor AS oa ON ( a.idautor = oa.idautor )
JOIN
  obra AS o ON ( oa.idobra = o.idobra )
LEFT JOIN
  obra_assunto AS oas ON ( o.idobra = oas.idobra )
LEFT JOIN
  assunto AS ass ON ( oas.idassunto = ass.idassunto );
```

A consulta acima vai recuperar somente os `Autores` que possuam `Obras` cadastradas. Se as `Obras` não possuirem `Assuntos` cadastrados, o campo contendo a `Descrição do Assunto` virá `NULL`.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/69101/5

Comment: Oi bom dia, nunca tentei fazer algo assim , usando joins.

Comment: você está usando e não sabe, só que com outra sintaxe rs